# Why the TOTAL continue added when enter every digit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate the total of the amount.
amount = qty*unitPrice

The calculation is working fine with one digit entered but when enter two or more digit, the total keep adding the previous amount of previous digit. 
For example :

- 100x1=100         --------> first digit '1' working fine
- 100x10=1100       --------> 2nd digit '0', start adding the previous
  amount, 1000+100
- 100x100=11100     --------> 3rd digit '0', 10000+1100
- 100x1000=111100   --------> 4th digit '0', 100000+11100

Below is the code,

```
   var total = 0; 

   function calculateTotal() {
        _datatableData.forEach(function (rowData) {
            var ID = rowData.ID;
            var unitPrice = parseFloat($("#txtUnitPrice" + ID).val(), 10);
            var quantity = parseInt($("#txtQuantity" + ID).val(), 10);

            if (!unitPrice) { unitPrice = 0; }
            if (!quantity) { quantity = 0; }

            amount = quantity * unitPrice;
            $("#txtAmount" + ID).val(amount);
       });
       total += amount;
       $("#createPOTotal").val(total);
    }
```

The google drive link below is the screenshot, 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oiqJESgg1lVtz-n9lxN1kQejHPfQ-wY3?usp=sharing

Comment: Why you defined total outside function . It becomes global variable and keeps old value into it

Comment: @crack_iT , I have defined the total inside the function, but when i add new row, the total back to 0.

Comment: Its the total variable that's outside the function which is causing this behaviour. move it inside and your code is fine.

Comment: @GaganDeep I have defined the total inside the function, but when i add new row, the total back to 0.

Comment: after adding adding the new row are you again calling the `calculateTotal()` function?

Comment: I have found the solution, the line 'total += amount' need to be inside the forEach. and the total need to defined inside the function.. others still the same. Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, the line 'total += amount' need to be inside the forEach. and the total need to defined inside the function.. others still the same.

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var total = 0; 
    var amount;
    _datatableData.forEach(function (rowData) {
        var ID = rowData.ID;
        var unitPrice = parseFloat($("#txtUnitPrice" + ID).val(), 10);
        var quantity = parseInt($("#txtQuantity" + ID).val(), 10);

        if (!unitPrice) { unitPrice = 0; }
        if (!quantity) { quantity = 0; }

        amount = quantity * unitPrice;
        $("#txtAmount" + ID).val(amount);
        total += amount;
   });

   $("#createPOTotal").val(total);
}
```